# In the context of the Axiom of Foundation: clarifying the text's discussion of the least element

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

In Stillwell's "Real Numbers," page 133, he says the least element in a ordinal $\sigma$ is $0$ or (using von Neumann's concept of natural numbers) the empty set $\{\}$.

My question is on the subsequent remark:

> > the least element in $\sigma - \{0\}$ is $\{0\}=1$.

I hope this is a typo, and he really means: the least element in $\sigma - \{\}$ which is $\{0\}=1$.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: I interpret $-$ as set-theoretic complement, so that $\sigma-\{0\}$ is the set of elements that are in $\sigma$ but are not in $\{0\}$, i.e. the set of elements in $\sigma$ which are not equal to $0$. In this case the statement is correct as written.

Comment: For any set $\sigma$, the set difference $\sigma - \{\} = \sigma - \emptyset = \sigma$.  On the other hand, $\sigma - \{ 0 \} = \{ \alpha \in \sigma : \alpha \notin \{ 0 \} \} = \{ \alpha \in \sigma : \alpha \ne 0 \}$ which looks exactly right to me.

Comment: @JulianRosen Thanks. (Having the right of first refusal) perhaps you would like to post your comment as an answer. Also, if its no further imposition, I would appreciate any reference suggestions to help me better understand these types of issues. With regards,

Comment: I don't have any references to suggest. If someone else does, he or she is welcome to post an answer.

Comment: @JulianRosen Thanks again - yet would post your comment as an answer?

Comment: This may be useful: the set $\{b, c\}$ is **not** $\{a, b, c\}-a$, but rather $\{a, b, c\}-\{a\}$. "$A-B$" means "remove each element of $B$ from $A$." In particular, $A-\emptyset=A$ for all $A$ ("remove nothing from $A$").

Comment: Since the empty set $\phi $ is an ordinal, if $\sigma=\phi$ then $\sigma$ has no least (or any element).  And if $\sigma=1=\{0\}$ then $\sigma$ has no $2$nd-least member. It should say "If $\phi \ne\sigma \in On$ then $\min \sigma =0=\phi.$" ....And "If $ \sigma \in On$ and $0\ne \sigma \ne 1$ then $\min (\sigma$ \ $\{0\})=1.$"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here $\sigma-\{0\}$ is the set of elements of $\sigma$ that are not elements of $\{0\}$, that is, the set of elements of $\sigma$ that are not equal to $0$. The remark in the text says that $1$ is the least element of $\sigma$ which is not $0$.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. For clarification, do $\sigma - \{\}$ or $\sigma-0$ have any meaning? With regards,

Comment: $\sigma-\{\}$ is the set of elements of $\sigma$ that are not elements of $\{\}$. Since nothing is an element of $\{\}$, we get $\sigma-\{\}=\sigma$ (Daniel Schepler mentioned this in the comments). As an ordinal number, $0=\{\}$, so it is also true that $\sigma-0=\sigma$, but writing it this way might be more likely to cause confusion.